# Android Studio + conan native code debugging

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, conan

I have recently switched from ndk-build to cmake build system in Android Studio (I'm using version 3.2.1) and, since I have dependencies in my C++ code to some third party libraries, I've decided to switch to conan C++ package manager to simplify my cross building. In order to do that properly, I've decided to try this on small example just to be sure that everything will work as expected.

I followed instructions from [Android studio integration](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/android_studio.html) page and everything compiles and runs fine, but I'm unable to debug native code from android studio. My breakpoints in C++ code are ignored.

When I removed all the code dependencies to the libpng library and in the CMakeLists.txt, commented out the

```
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)
```

line I was able to debug C++ code again.

I tried to dig into the "conan_basic_setup" cmake macro, but I got lost inside.
I even tried creating debug conan profile for cross compilation by changing

```
build_type=Release
```

into

```
build_type=Debug
```

in the profile file but without result.

Anyone have the receipt for the correct setup for debugging?

Comment: Typically, the conan packages do not package all the debug artifacts in case of Windows (.pdbs are big), or might suffer from the problem of relocation (paths of pre-compiled packages to sources are different in the original machine that built them, wrt to the user machine). I would suggest trying the issue tracker: https://github.com/conan-io/conan or the #conan slack channel in CppLang team, for more interactive discussions.

Comment: I didn't mention, but my build environment is on linux machine and I have local conan server. All dependencies are built locally. I did post an issue on their tracker as well as here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to resolve it by adding parameter NO_OUTPUT_DIRS to the conan_basic_setup macro.

So instead of

```
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)
```

it should be

```
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS NO_OUTPUT_DIRS)
```

Apparently, without this parameter conan alters the bin/ and lib/ output path and mess the android studio's setup.
Now I can debug my code.